# Screen Coordinates of UITextField Within A UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextfield, screen, coordinates

Situation:  Have a UITextField instance which is a subview of a UIScrollView.
Need: Screen relative coordinates of the UITextField instance
This sounds so simple but it eludes me.
Could someone give me some pointers on how to do this.
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, tada:
textField.frame.origin.y + scrollView.frame.origin.y - scrollView.frame.contentOffset.y

Comment: Obviously that only works if your UIScrollView isn't configured to zoom! A generic solution is to use UIScrollView's (inherited from UIView) `convertPoint` or `convertFrame` methods.

Comment: You saved my day!! Tried so many things nothing worked except this one with my scenario